# Authentication with Azure for an ionic mobile app without opening Azure Login Page

Tags: angularjs, azure, ionic-framework

I want to authenticate My Ionic App using Azure AD By entering username and password on my custom Login and posting data without opening Azure AD login Page.
Please Provide sample code or LINK .Thanks In Advance

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

Comment: Hi @Avinash Thanks For the Help but This library opens the Azure login page. But i don't want the user to redirect to the Azure Login page i just want to post username and want response back